# templates, products and teasers

Tags: 7, theming

I do not really know where to look anymore. I'm using D7 and Drupal Commerce and I would like to display a block using a rendered entity. I created my node--product-display--new-teaser.tpl.php and everything works fine, until I try to load a field from the related product: field_images.
The difference is that in the default version field_images display using an imagezoom, while the new node: new-teaser (that I have created under product display) only display the first image.

What I would like to do, is to render in my node--product-display--new-teaser.tpl.php the field_images coming from the node: new-teaser new product display mode.

Comment: What are the field display settings for this New Teaser view mode?

Comment: for new-teaser is: Modify the settings for this field on the product variation type "manage display" configuration. then, in "node: new-teaser", the product variation, I only display the first image as rendered image, but this is what I cannot achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what I am trying to do:
in your **product_display** display mode, in your product field, you chose: rendered entity, and in rendered entity options, you will be able to select your new **product** display mode.

I hope this helps somebody.